# Storing less secure hash for password in memory, as tradeoff for performance?

Tags: security, hash, passwords, cryptography, password-hash

I am currently working on a project what involves storing and validating passwords. The passwords are hashed with 100,000 iterations, and then persisted to the database, which is later retrieved and verified when the user logs in.  It works well because during low load, the hashing takes ~1 sec to generate, and most users find the delay acceptable.

The issue is that as the system gets more and more users (~100 concurrent) the hashing is now maxing out the cpu and takes over 6secs to generate -- this leads to a very slow log on time, and unfortunately the system has a stateless api which require validation of the password on every call.

As I understand it, we want to make the hashing expensive to compute to avoid bruce force attacks, but given that it's far less likely that the attacker can gain access to our memory dump then the database, I am thinking to implement a compromise where after a successful log on, I'll hash the password with less iteration (e.g., 5000) and store that in memory for a short period of time. If a request comes in wanting to validate the same user id, I'd use the in-memory, less-secure version to validate, otherwise I'd use the more secure version in the database.  This prevent attacks with access to our db bruce forcing our db, and in high-load scenario, most requests can be satisfied by the in-memory less-expensive hash.

I realize that this is less secure, but is it a reasonable trade off? Any gotchas I should watch out for?

Adrian

Comment: This hashing/authentication is often only be done *once* per user/session-logon; after that some form of authentication token/nonce (e.g. cookie) generally takes over. Is there 100 concurrent *authentication attempts* against said password store? Also, I'm not sure how one would get a "less hashed/secure" hash from a "more hashed/secure" hash as being able to do so would mean that the hash is reversible.

Comment: In any case, it may be worthwhile to *offload* authentication onto additional systems/hardware if such bottlenecks are truly are occuring.

Comment: Unforunately, our API is stateless, so no session; each call from the client will be a new log on. If we successfully validated a password, I have the client-text password again (the one that passes) and I can generate the less-secure version from that.

Comment: Does the client *always* send their password? That sounds .. fishy, although it is how BC works :> If it were my system I would try to avoid such design.

Comment: yeah; it's kind of a legacy system so the clients periodically (every 5 mins) log on using their credentials.

Comment: Okay, rolling with that as a restriction (ick!) - How would it be possible to generate a "low hashed" hash from the stored "more hashed" hash such that it can be stored in memory? I guess directly from the submitted password on a successful login? In which case I have to wonder if the [in memory] cache is compromised (e.g. system level access that can read/dump other process memory), what would using hashes at this level add?

Comment: Yes; that's the concern as well. But I am hoping that it's less likely and therefore a less secure version (5000 iterations) is sufficient, esp since it only last in memory for a short period of time (I am thinking, 15 mins?) before being cleared.

Comment: The entire point of repeated hashing to slow down brute force attacks to "discourage" such vectors. So you'd have to figure how desired the data is - if said hash data was available, but no raw information was exposed for some unlikely reason - how much money/hardware would an attacker use in a brute force situation? The more important the data, the more the attacker will invest. By reducing repeated hashing (by such and such a factor) it's just a numbers game of how much faster (by such and such a factor) a determined attacker can generate said hashes.

Comment: (In any case, I'd suspect an attacker with such access could just as easily access the plain-text data and mitigate any need to deal with the hashes. Also, make sure you're using adequate salt of course - or else the number of repeated hashing is largely irrelevant. In addition, some hashes like SHA-x have lots of specialized hardware so favor something like bcrpyt/scrypt if possible.)

Comment: I don't understand I guess.  You say your system is stateless yet you're hanging onto data (a special version of the password), correlating it with a key held by the browser (the user ID), and hanging onto it for a temporary period (15 minutes).  Sounds an awful lot like a session to me.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds confusing, but I didn't think I mentioned browsers before -- I am working on a stateless API and there are no browsers involved. Also, the temporary data is used for caching, not for session management; so it is a cached stateless system instead of a session...